# Can't get default values to work with custom shortcode

Tags: shortcode, embed

I'm working on creating a shortcode to embed locally hosted Quicktime movies, but I can't seem to get the default attributes to stick. Here's what I'm working with, can anyone spot anything obviously wrong? The result gives me no value for an unspecified attribute at all (in this case height/width), rather than the desired defaults of 480 and 320. If specified, it works as intended.

```
<?php
function quicktime_embedder( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
        'url' => '#',
        'width' => '480',
        'height' => '320'
    ), $atts ) );

    return '<object classid="clsid:02BF25D5-8C17-4B23-BC80-D3488ABDDC6B"
                codebase="http://www.apple.com/qtactivex/qtplugin.cab" height="300" width="500">
                <param name="src" value="http://www.yoursite.com/video/video1.mov">
                <param name="autoplay" value="false">
                <param name="controller" value="true">
                <param name="type" value="video/quicktime" height="'.$atts[height].'" width="'.$atts[width].'">
                <embed src="'.$atts[url].'"
                     height="'.$atts[height].'" width="'.$atts[width].'" autoplay="false" type="video/quicktime"
                 pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">
            </object>';
}

add_shortcode( 'quicktime', 'quicktime_embedder' );

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`extract`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php) takes and associative array and explodes it out in variables that reflect the array key names.  `$atts['height']` would just be `$height`, in other words.

The relevant two lines of your code would become:

```
<param name="type" value="video/quicktime" height="'.$height.'" width="'.$width.'">
<embed src="'.$url.'" height="'.$height.'" width="'.$width.'" autoplay="false" type="video/quicktime" pluginspage="http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/">
```

If you did still want to use the indexing, make sure you surround array keys with quotes: `$atts['height']` not $atts[height].  Replace `extract`:

```
$atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'url' => '#',
        'width' => '480',
        'height' => '320'
    ), $atts )
```

Comment: Perfect! I didn't understand `extract` correctly. That got me exactly what I needed, thank you so much!